# Where to put generic type

Tags: java, generics

I'm new on this and at the moment I cant prove this by myself so, lets say I have this code

```
private ArrayList<Integer> array;

public ArrayList set(ArrayList newArray) {
        return something;
    }
```

Should I write the Integer in the method type? Should I also do it in the method input type? How can I know exactly when to do it?

Comment: Well, a setter is usually `void` (what `something` do you want to return, other than possibly `newArray`)? And, I assume, `array` is the thing you want to **set** so ask yourself, what type is `array`? Also, you should prefer the `List` interface to the `ArrayList` concrete type. Finally, there is almost **never** a reason to use raw types; that is `ArrayList` (or `List` or any generic class) without a type.

Comment: In your example, you should put it on both.

Comment: You should essentially _never_ have `ArrayList` without some angle brackets, usually with something between them, immediately afterward.

Comment: It seems that there's a gap in understanding here. I would recommend reviewing [Java Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_variables.asp), [Java Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp), [Java Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp), [Java Method Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_param.asp), [Java Array List](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp), and [List vs Array List](https://www.java67.com/2016/01/difference-between-list-and-arraylist-variable-in-java.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> set(ArrayList<Integer> newArray) {
        return something;
}
```

Would be be correct. Usually your IDE also tells you when to add the generic type and not use the raw type. It can also tell you when you can omit the type and make use of type inference. eg.

```
// no type needed. Compiler can infer the type.
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

I would recommend to take a look at this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html